# Interesting tags lost after adding OpenId

Tags: support, openid, tag-watching

I added a new OpenID recently and I lost all my interesting tags. None of them are to be seen in my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96780) or home page.

I also lost my recently awarded Pundit badge momentarily, but right now I've got it back. And I keep earning an abnormally high number of new Good Answer and Nice Answer badges, which I suspect I actually had before - I can't remember.

I would have assumed that logging in with a different OpenId would just give me access to exactly the same data, only through a second entry point. Instead of adding a second door to my house, now I see that some furniture has been changed.

---

**Update.** It looks like I created a second profile which later the system merged with incomplete data from the first one. I must say the whole process is looks highly counter intuitive to me (I just wanted a second way to log in to *my* existing profile), but it may be forced by the specific implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've created multiple accounts instead of adding. Email team@stackoverflow.com with URLs to your profiles.

Comment: Well it looks like the "old" profile which I can remember by heart (http://stackoverflow.com/users/35135) is no longer there, so somehow the system has "sorted it out". Maybe it's time to start a new SO life, without interesting tags.